# "API Gateway managed resources are view only."

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am trying to create some authorization setup such that my Lambda function can return sound files in my S3 bucket to stream, however I'm running into the following issue:

[image: Gateway Resources View Only]

It seems I can't attach an authorizer to this route. I'll admit I'm fairly new to this, but when I Googled this message I couldn't really find an answer as to why that is, and how to unlock adding an authorization. Do I have to create a new route other than default to do this? What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is particularly happening, when you choose a $default as stage.

If we choose `$default` as a stage, it is not letting us modify the integration